# Install Drush in my windows system without composer

Tags: windows, drupal

How to install drush in my windows 10 system without using composer.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why do you want not to use Composer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're stuck, because Composer is required to install the latest version of Drush on Windows. If you still want to install it anyway here are the instructions. <sup>[source](https://www.drupal.org/node/594744)</sup>

1. Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

   1. Install ncurses package. You need to select ncurses manually in cygwin setup. If you don't install this you will get an error message that tput is missing.
   2. Install Git package.
   3. Install bsdtar package or you cannot restore archives and get errors like `Unable to untar` and `Unable to extract site archive tarball`.
   4. Install Curl package or you cannot disable modules.
2. Now install [Composer for Windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows) globally.
3. Install [Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/) the common way. e.g. Drush 8.x (stable):

   ```
   composer global require drush/drush:8.*
   ```

Note: Drush 9 aka the "master" branch only works with Drupal 8.